# Change while loop to Stream but missing the last element

Tags: scala

I've tried to replace my while loop with Stream but when I use the Stream version, the last element is always missing. I think I understand why it's missing but I can't figure how to fix this. Any Suggesting? also is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Using Stream:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst) {
val result = Stream.continually((
  Song(
    cursor.getLong(c(BaseColumns._ID)),
    cursor.getString(c(MediaColumns.TITLE))     
  ),
  cursor.moveToNext))
.takeWhile(_._2)
.map(_._1)
result.toList
}
```

Here is the while loop version works fine.

```
cursor.moveToFirst()
var i = 0
var list: List[Song] = List.empty
while (i < cursor.getCount()) {
  val s = Song(
    cursor.getLong(c(BaseColumns._ID)),
    cursor.getString(c(MediaColumns.TITLE)))
  i = i + 1
  list = list :+ s
  cursor.moveToNext()
```

Note:

moveToNext

Move the cursor to the next row.
This method will return false if the cursor is already past the last entry in the result set.

Comment: What would happen if `cursor` has ***NO*** element?

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst will return false. ok i need to edit the code a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have one entry.  You produce the tuple

```
(song, false)
```

and throw it away.  That's clearly no good.  You want to keep the song even though there's not *another* song there!  So instead you might try an option--load a song if there is one, don't if there isn't.  You also have to handle the first element differently since `moveToFirst` is not the same as `moveToNext`. Like so:

```
def loadSong = Song(
  cursor.getLong(c(BaseColumns._ID)),
  cursor.getString(c(MediaColumns.TITLE))     
)

if (cursor.moveToFirst) {
  val songs = Stream(Some(loadSong)) ++
    Stream.continually(if (cursor.moveToNext()) Some(loadSong) else None)
  songs.flatten.toList
}
```

Note that you're not actually using the streaminess of streams here, so you could just as well use `Iterator.continually`.

Note: I might instead move the wrapping logic to `someLong` and produce something like this instead:

```
def loadSong(b: Boolean) = if (!b) None else Some(Song(
  cursor.getLong(c(BaseColumns._ID)),
  cursor.getString(c(MediaColumns.TITLE))     
))

val songs = Stream(loadSong(cursor.moveToFirst())) ++
    Stream.continually(loadSong(cursor.moveToNext())
songs.flatten.toList
```

or, given the method I have in my personal library:

```
def optIn[A](b: Boolean)(a: => A) = if (b) Some(a) else None
```

the plain loadSong from before with

```
val songs = Stream(optIn(cursor.moveToFirst)(loadSong)) ++
  Stream.continually(optIn(cursor.moveToNext)(loadSong))
songs.flatten.toList
```

is probably the most compact and readable.  (Once you know how to read `optIn`.)

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor is a sort of iterator, just less convenient. So as an alternative to Rex Kerr's answer, you could abstract away the whole transformation between your `cursor` to an `Iterator` (or `Stream`) so that you have a way to iterate over your cursor like this:

```
def loadSong(c: Cursor) = (
  c.getLong(c(BaseColumns._ID)),
  c.getString(c(MediaColumns.TITLE))     
)

cursor.map(loadSong).toList
```

For that you just need an implicit conversion from your `Cursor` to an `Iterator[Cursor]` where the cursor is in the proper state (ready to be read from) at each iteration. An implementation could be:

```
implicit def cursor2Iterator(c: Cursor): Iterator[Cursor] = if (c.moveToFirst) 
  new NonEmptyCursorIterator(c) else Iterator.empty

sealed class NonEmptyCursorIterator(private val c: Cursor) extends Iterator[Cursor] {
    private[this] var hasNext0 = true // always has at least one element

    def hasNext() = {
      if (!hasNext0) hasNext0 = c.moveToNext
      hasNext0
    }

    def next(): Cursor = if (hasNext()) {
      hasNext0 = false 
      c
    } else throw new NoSuchElementException("hasNext() is false")
}
```

That makes for short and readable code.